# Refresh extjs form's submit data

Tags: extjs

I have an extjs form (GET method) where some fields can be dynamically added or removed. i have also added a logic that changes names of fields for example

```
....
items: [
         {
           xtype: 'textfield',
           fieldLabel: 'Username',
           name: 'data[param1][0]'
         },{
....
```

becomes

```
....
items: [
         {
           xtype: 'textfield',
           fieldLabel: 'Username',
           name: 'data[param1][1]'
         },{
....
```

After I submit the form old data is submitted without any effect on added/removed fields or field name changes

How to update or refresh form so it send correct.

**EDIT**
Everything else is working correctly in this form for example form.load() loads the data from server side json and i can edit/save them back to db. when i use form.add(fields) method new fields are included in submit request but not delete. I read that EXJS form submit url data is calculated one time and other time when possibly some events are triggered.

Main trouble is renaming the fields does not reflect submit data, i have checked manually by looking source that field names are changed properly from my logic. I call form.doLayout() after making changes in fields

Comment: There's not enough detail in your post. How does the load work? After you load it, how are you pushing that info into the form? Also, is the `GET` being cached, so that when you get your field definitions it's returning the same thing?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli GET is not cached because it has timestamp in url and i am looking requests from firebug, pls find the more details in EDIT